# How to replace a whole line with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

Suppose I have a file with lines

```
aaa=bbb
```

Now I would like to replace them with:

```
aaa=xxx
```

I can do that as follows:

```bash
sed "s/aaa=bbb/aaa=xxx/g"
```

Now I have a file with a few lines as follows:

```
aaa=bbb
aaa=ccc
aaa=ddd
aaa=[something else]
```

How can I replace *all* these lines `aaa=[something]` with `aaa=xxx` using *sed*?

Comment: Is `[something else]` the literal text, or is that just a placeholder? What is the possible format of the thing after the equals sign?

Comment: that is more of a regex question not a sed question.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
sed "s/aaa=.*/aaa=xxx/g"
```

Comment: Force of habit, it can be ignored in this case - it's used as a global replacement for the line to replace each match rather than just the first. In this case though only the first will be matched because of the `.*`.

Comment: Michael J. Barber, `g` replace all the instance of regexp with replacement

Comment: Add `-i` to change the file in place

Answer (score 207):

You can also use sed's change line to accomplish this:

```bash
sed -i "/aaa=/c\aaa=xxx" your_file_here
```

This will go through and find any lines that pass the `aaa=` test, which means that the line contains the letters `aaa=`.  Then it replaces the entire line with aaa=xxx.  You can add a `^` at the beginning of the test to make sure you only get the lines that start with `aaa=` but that's up to you.

Comment: OS X's `sed` requires `c` to be followed by a backslash and a newline, and it doesn't append a newline to the inserted text, but you can use for example `$'/aaa=/c\\\naaa=xxx\n'`.

Comment: Here's and example in the sed documentation of the [change/replace feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Replacing-selected-lines-with-other-text) that @Mr. T is talking about.

Comment: This is the closest to actually doing what was asked... (But Lri's version is needed for portability)

Comment: What I like about it: if you match a *range* of lines, the `c` will replace the entire range with just a single line:  `'/garbage_start/,/garbage_stop/c\[Garbage skipped]'`   The `s` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 56):

Like this:

```bash
sed 's/aaa=.*/aaa=xxx/'
```

If you want to guarantee that the `aaa=` is at the start of the line, make it:

```bash
sed 's/^aaa=.*/aaa=xxx/'
```

Comment: What if I want to replace with aaa='xxxx'. I tried escaping like `sed 's/aaa=.*/aaa=\'xxx\'/'` but that opens up a `>` prompt in a new line...

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes like ```sed "s/aaa=.*/aaa='xxx'/g"```

Answer (score 6):

```bash
sed -i.bak 's/\(aaa=\).*/\1"xxx"/g' your_file
```

Comment: -i.bak. Didn't know about this one. Really neat trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use `awk` then this would work too

```bash
awk -F= '{$2="xxx";print}' OFS="\=" filename
```

Comment: How does this check for "aaa" pattern?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! | sed '/aaa=\(bbb\|ccc\|ddd\)/!s/\(aaa=\).*/\1xxx/'
> aaa=bbb
> aaa=ccc
> aaa=ddd
> aaa=[something else]
!
aaa=bbb
aaa=ccc
aaa=ddd
aaa=xxx
```

Comment: I don't think an explicit check for `bbb`, `ccc`, and `ddd` is quite what the OP had in mind.