# Replace possible phrases with word in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to be able to replace entire phrases like:

```
white_phone
white; phone
white.phone
phone;white
```

with a single phrase "REJECT" based on whether the word "white" is in the phrase. I have tried using:

`sed -e 's/*white*/REJECT/g' -e 's/*white/REJECT/g' -e 's/white*/REJECT/g' file`

but this only replaces the word "white" and leaves the remainder of the phrase, which I don't want.

The phrases are tab delimited too, if that helps.

Comment: This question might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822097/how-to-replace-whole-line-with-sed

Comment: Say _phrases_, but in the 4 examples you provided, a _pharse_ coincide with a _line_, so I'd think that you are actually referring to _lines_; however you explicitly specify that the _phrases are tab delimited too_. What do you mean? That you can have multiple _phrases_, tab-seprated, on a single line? If this is the case, please add an example to cover also this usecase.

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) has some hints for beginners.

Comment: Answers are good but explanations of why? The easy explanation is `*` on its own is not a regex, you need `.*`

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the output you want, as I understand you neeed. If it is not the case, please show an example of your desired output.

```
sed -i 's/.*white.*/REJECT/' file
```

Comment: `g` is not required

Comment: You are absolutly right :) thanks! I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sed backreferences for this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^.*\)white.*phone\(.*$\)/\1REJECT\2/g' -e 's/\(^.*\)phone.*white\(.*$\)/\1REJECT\2/g' < file
```

That command works for me with the input you provided.

Comment: This does not work with an input line which does not contain the word _phone_; the OP says _based on whether the word "white" is in the phrase_, therefore unless he's worded the question very poorly, this answer does not address his request.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/white/cREJECT' file
```