# Replace a string in second quotations?

Tags: regex, bash

I have line in my swagger.json file that can outputted with `grep host swagger.json`:

```
  "host": "there.can.be.nothing.or.anything.here",
```

so I want to replace the string in second quotations `there.can.be.nothing.or.anything.here` I just put that value as an example, I might put empty quotes here like `""` or some domain `"example.com"` the importat thing is that I replace everything within second quotes.

So lets say If I want to replace it with the string `some.domain.com` (possibly with sed command?):

I will have this line edited in my swagger:

```
  "host": "some.domain.com",
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822097/how-to-replace-a-whole-line-with-sed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a json file and so use jq.

```
jq '.host="some.domain.com"' swagger.json
```

If you can't use json for what ever reason, use sed:

```
sed -ri 's/(^.*host\": \")(.*)(\".*$)/\1some.domain.com\3/' swagger.json
```

Split the host line into three sections and substitute the line for the first second followed by the amended text and the third section.

Comment: sed command works! Thanks! jq command doesn't work (I was using a test file with only that line, maybe that's why) and I'm not sure the docker container that will run these commands will have jq, is jq part of bash?

Comment: Yeah, the structure of the file is important with the jq command.