# How can I get configmap value where the key is dynamic in Kubernetes

Tags: regex, kubernetes, environment-variables, configmap

In one of my deployment files, I want to set an environment variable. The variable is `KUBE_VERSION` and values must be fetched from a ConfigMap.

```
  kube_1_21: 1.21.10_1550
```

This is part of ConfigMap where I want to set `1.21.10_1550` to `KUBE_VERSION`, but if the cluster is of IKS 1.20, then the key will be:

```
kube_1_20: 1.20.21_3456
```

`kube_` is always static. How can I set environment variable using a regex expression?

Something of this sort:

```
 - name: KUBE_VERSION
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                 name: cluster-info
                 key: "kube_1*"
```

Comment: Does `key: "kube_1.*"` work?

Comment: No. It throws error. Invalid value: "kube_[0-1][0-9]": a valid config key must consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.' (e.g. 'key.name',  or 'KEY_NAME',  or 'key-name', regex used for validation is '[-._a-zA-Z0-9]+')

Comment: Could you explain why you need this configuration? A workaround maybe could I find.

Comment: To deploy certain sidecars in Pod depending on the kubernetes version. Say I need external snapshooter only for IKS > 1.23

Comment: Did you see [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables)? In this exercise, you create a Pod that has one Container. Here is the configuration file for the Pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is unfortunately not possible to use the regular expression as you would like. Additionally, you have information about the regular expression that validates the entered data:

> regex used for validation is '[-._a-zA-Z0-9]+')

It follows that you have to enter `key` as an alphanumeric string and additionally you can use the characters `-`, `_` and `.` So it is not possible to use regex in this place.

To workaround you can write your custom script i.e. in Bash and replace the proper line with [sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822097/how-to-replace-a-whole-line-with-sed).